# How would I populate prior counts for an entity based off of current counts of data that can be filtered by user selected dates in PowerBi?

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, data-analysis, reporting

I have been working in power BI for a couple weeks now but have been struggling with getting a DAX query to work the way I need it to for a matrix heatmap I am building. I am working with healthcare related data and we are trying to build a visualization that would show us the current count of data for a given period for things like lab tests and vitals, compared to the previous count of data.  This is to help us determine when we are missing or are not receiving data from each entity that sends data daily.

Data structure looks as follows:

[image]
There are two parts to what I am trying to accomplish

Part 1:
We sum the current counts up to get a total count of data for each entity which I have figured out.

The data will all be filtered by 'creation date'. The creation date will have a start and end date, where the start date is the creation_date value and the end date is the creation_date value minus 1 day.  The logic would look as follows:

```
 WHERE CREATION_DATE >= [user_selected_value] AND CREATION_DATE < [user_selected_value] +     timedelta(days =1))
```

The first thing I am stumped on is how to best create a date filter that would consider the creation_date -1 day and then set that as the end date.

The prior count part I am also having issues wrapping my head around how to go about this. To populate the prior count, we would look back at the count but for the time period the report user selects when they pick the creation_date begin date and creation_date end date period.

Part 2:
We want to then create a flag for each prior count and current count entity key value pair. The logic would look as follows for the flag:

```
if (current_count>0)&(prior_count>0): return 1
if (current_count>0)&(prior_count==0): return 2
if (current_count==0)&(prior_count>0): return 3
return 4
```

The current_count and prior_count and flag value would all need to change with the date filters selected by the user as well.

I am not sure how best to go about this part either.

So to sum up, my main questions/parts I need help with would be:

1. How do I best create a date filter that would consider a date -1 day and then set that as a seperate column labled end_date?
2. How do I populate a prior count that would look back at the count for a given entity but for the time period the report user selects when they pick the creation_date begin date and creation_date end date?

3)How would I then create a flag for each entities prior count and current count pairs that would consider a users date selection?

Hopefully this is enough information I can add more data if needed or clarify further just completely stumped on this one and have limited experience with DAX queries, thanks!

I tried the following by couldnt get any of these to work the way I need them to work:

I thought maybe if I did a 12 month period then I could utilize that as the prior count but thats not really the requirements and wouldnt work for what I need.

```
prior_count
    = CALCULATE (
        SUM ( vw_feed_health_documents[entity_id] ),
        DATESINPERIOD (
            vw_feed_health_documents[creation_date],
            MAX ( vw_feed_health_documents[creation_date] ),
            -12,
            MONTH
        )
    )
```

I tried to utilize the earlier function in various ways but couldnt get that to work either.

Comment: Bit of a massive question.  I'm not quite following if you are trying to create a new column in part 1 or return an expression over a custom date filter.

Comment: @AmericanLuke yeah I should have probably broken these up into two seperate posts but also this is just a complex issue to begin with.  Ill clarify the questions better as well after rereading I see how it is confusing.  So the first thing I would need to do is create a date filter that will always subtract 1 day from creation_date and then that result would become the end_date column.

Comment: So, 'end_date = creation_date - 1' ? Not quite sure what you mean by a filter that results in a column.

Comment: @AmericanLuke yes end_date = creation_date - 1, I did find a tutorial here that is explaining what I am trying to accomplish with at least the date part but still confused on the other parts, https://blog.enterprisedna.co/show-days-before-or-after-a-selected-date-using-power-bi/

Comment: So you want the user to select a start and end date, and for the report to calculate the count for all dates between the start and end date, inclusive?